# setTimeout() not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var account;
var users = ["********"];
var password = "*********";
var gameId = 126945035 //Put your game ID here

for (account = 0; account < users.length; account++) {
    window.location.assign('www.roblox.com');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = users[account];
        document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = password;
        document.getElementById('LoginButton').click();
        setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.assign('http://www.roblox.com/Game/PlaceLauncher.ashx?request=RequestGame&placeId=' + gameId);
            setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.assign('http://www.roblox.com/---place?id=' + gameId);
                $('.upvote').click();
            }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

When I run that, it is supposed to log into the account, which seems to be working, but after I use the setTimeout() it won't run anything after that.

All of the *'s are information that I can't share.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your code directed towards roblox.com?

Comment: I am making something to automatically login, then 'thumbs up' a place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're leaving the current webpage in the first `setTimeout`. This is not caused by the `setTimeout` function, rather the fact that you're leaving the page.

The [Location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.assign)method causes the window to load and display page of the URL argument.

That basically means that, the moment you fire `window.location.assign('url')`, you force the page to reload. This stops any other lines of code from being processed.

You'll likely want to either

a) Make ajax requests to initialize your authentication process

b) Use traditional post-back requests to store the state of the first url's request in a session. The second page visited in the workflow will then have the proper credentials.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ajax at all, could you give me an example on how I would use it in this situation?

Comment: That's hard to answer without a deeper knowledge of your application. You might just want to create a form with the authentication url as an action and a successful post will redirect to the second url.

Comment: I'm not that advanced, but I think that is what I'm going for. I want it to login, which is what all the elements are for, then I want to go to the link, to trick the website saying that I 'visited' the game already, after that It would navigate to the games URL, and click the .upvote class.